# use signal alarm in multi-threads OpenCV program

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, opencv

I am writting an OpevCV program,a multi-thread program,one of threads should receive *alarm* signal.It's a little complicated.To show where the problem is,i wrote the test code,like below:

MainThread:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{ 
   cout << "main thread = " << pthread_self() << endl;
   sigset_t set;
   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGALRM);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

   struct sigaction sa;
   sa.sa_handler = int_handler;
   sa.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
   sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL);

   pthread_t thread;
   if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, capturePictures, NULL) < 0)
   {
       cerr << "pthread_create error" << endl;
       return -1;
   }
   alarm(5);
   pthread_join(thread, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

ChildThread:

```
void *capturePictures(void* arg)
{
    cout << "capturePictures thread = " << pthread_self() << endl;
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGALRM);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);

    string rtsp = "rtsp://admin:admin12345@192.168.0.81:554/h264/cha1/main/av_stream";

    VideoCapture vcap;
    if(!vcap.open(rtsp)) {
        cout << "open stream error" << endl;
        return (void *)-1;
    }

    unsigned int picIndex = 0;
    int index = 0;
    Mat image;

    while(1){
        if (!vcap.read(image)){
            cout <<"read image error" << endl;
            return (void*)-1;
        }

        if (picIndex++ % 25 != 0) continue;

        char fileName[30];
        sprintf(fileName,"pictures/%d.jpg",++index);
        imwrite(fileName, image);
    }
}
```

int_handler:

```
void int_handler(int signum)
{
    cout << "int_handler = " << pthread_self() << endl;
}
```

This test code doesn't mean anthing,just want to show you where the problem is.
The output is like this:

```
main thread = 140334223800320
capturePictures thread = 140333923575552
int_handler = 140333931968256
```

int_handler isn't called in main thread nor capturePictures thread(child thread),i don't even know which thread's id is *140333931968256*,i just create one child thread...
If i want to achieve my goal,how can i do?

Comment: Are you sure the signal you're printing is the SIGALRM you're waiting for? I think your SIGALRM may be delivered to the main thread and wait for the signal handler to unblock. Try ignoring the signal in the main thread rather than blocking. Also print the signal number from your handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i did something you suggest: 1.The the signal i am printing is the SIGALARM. 2.I don't think i can ignore the signal in the main thread ,cause you know it's a multi thread program,if i ingore the signal in the main thread,then all the theads will ignore it. 3. The most strange thing is where this 140333931968256 thread id come from,i didn't create it at all.

Comment: You're correct. I forgot that sigaction was for the whole process. Have you tried looking at it in a debugger?

Comment: It seems like 140333931968256  thread is  created by opencv.I just dont understand,i block the ALARM signal at the begining of main thread,how can this 140333931968256 thread receive ALARM?